# обновил локальный репозиторий,запушил и получилась каша из старых и новых файлов

Tags: git

Решил обновить файлы в гите. Зашел в папку проекта,удалил все старые файлы,добавил новые. Сделал git add *, git push. Теперь в репозитории каша из старых и новых файлов[image: введите сюда описание изображения]. Объясните необучаемому,как теперь удалить старые файлы? Cпасибо

Comment: Какой shell использовали? Bash? Делали ли `git commit` перед `git push`?

Comment: а удалил ты `git rm`'ом?

Comment: удалил просто через интерфейс,отправив в корзину. Делал git add*, git commit "new commit", git push

Comment: Надо теперь понять разницу между **index** и **working tree**.

Answer (score 1):

удаление отслеживаемого файла в рабочей копии хранилища для программы *git* в принципе эквивалентно действию «удалили все строки из этого файла», что и покажет команда `diff`:

```
$ git diff
diff --git a/file b/file
deleted file mode 100644
index ee579e6..0000000
--- a/file
+++ /dev/null
@@ -1,3 +0,0 @@
-первая строка
-вторая строка
-третья и последняя строка
```

чтобы закоммитить такое изменение для файла, можно сделать что-нибудь одно из перечисленного (список не исчерпывающий):

1. отправить изменение в index

   1. либо указав имя (имена) файла (файлов):

      ```
      $ git add file ...
      ```
   2. либо указав весь текущий каталог — будут учтены изменения во всех отслеживаемых файлах (включая под-каталоги):

      ```
      $ git add .
      ```

      p.s. указывать надо именно текщий каталог (`.`), а не «все файлы» (`*`), ведь этих файлов в данный момент уже нет (в рабочей копии)
   3. либо отправить изменения в index, не указывая имени (имён) файла (файлов), а указав опцию `-u` — «отправить изменения во всех отслеживаемых файлах»:

      ```
      $ git add -u
      ```

   и потом закоммитить:

   ```
   $ git commit
   ```
2. сразу закоммитить, указав опцию `-a` — «закоммитить все изменения из индекса и все изменеия во всех отслеживаемых файлах, ещё не отправленные в index»:

   ```
   $ git commit -a
   ```

---

но вообще можно было пойти и другим путём — не удалять файлы самому, а поручить это программе *git*: у неё тоже есть команда `rm`.

преимущесто: программа *git* не только удалит сами файлы, но и сразу отправит эти изменения в индекс.

надо либо указать файл (файлы):

```
$ git rm file ...
```

либо указать весь текущий каталог (в этом случае наверняка понадобится опций `-r` — «действовать рекурсивно» — ведь скорее всего у вас есть и под-каталоги). тогда будут удалены все отслеживаемые файлы (и ставшие в результате пустыми под-каталоги):

```
$ gi rm -r .
```

ну а затем уже закоммитить это изменение:

```
$ git commit
```

---

а что же получилось у вас? да просто куча незакреплённых изменений, которые можно увидеть, например, командой `status`. типа такого:

```
$ git status
On branch master
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add/rm <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

    deleted:    dir/file
    deleted:    file

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

и как с ними быть — сама программа и подсказывает (ну и в ответе выше написано).

Comment: @FatZer а смысл? ни я, ни git, ни автор вопроса про это не упоминают.

Comment: ИМХО это то что часто может вызывать затруднение/непонимание... ЗЫ: для протокола, комментарий удалил случайно — кнопки «править» и «удалить» были близко...

Comment: @Fat-Zer, может, лучше по этому поводу отдельный вопросо-ответ написать? а от и так ответ громоздкий получился. а в виду того, что мне такая ситуация не представляется затруднительной/непонятной — вам и карты в руки! p.s. для читающих и не понимающих о чём речь: предложено описать, почему в такой ситуации не сработает `git add *`

Comment: ладно... оставим это на совести вопрошающего... будет непонятно — переспросит ;)

Comment: @Fat-Zer, впрочем, придумал, как написать об этом кратко. сейчас дополню ответ.

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin, Спасибо большое за развернутый ответ.Помогло)

Comment: @dextroza: «[Что делать с ответами на мой вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)»